# LibreOffice Writer opens on top of document

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, libreoffice

Just got done upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from 12.04 LTS on two computers. One is a System 76 the other was an Apple min mac that I completely converted to Ubuntu, I can stand OS X and or Apple.

Problem is when I save a LibreOffice Writer always opens on top of document.

Where previously LibreOffice Writer open documents to the last pace I was editing them.

How do I set Googling  LibreOffice Writer to open at the place where I saved it last.

I tried checking LibreOffice Writer options and I could find anything that worked. I tried Googling the problem and found nothing even close to what I I am looking to do.

Thant you in advance, Mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this answer](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/1144/how-to-save-cursor-position-in-writer/):

"The cursor position is saved if you fill in the personal information(first and last name are enough). Go to Tools, Options, User Data.

When the user is identified, LibreOffice will open the document where the user left off. This makes sense because a different user opening the same document will probably want to start from the beginning. If there is no user identification LibreOffice assumes it is a new user and always opens from the beginning."

Comment: It's not working on Version: 6.0.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Works perfect.
Need to put your first, last and middle initial in:
LibreOffice main menu → Tools → Options → LibreOffice, triangle down →User Data → Fill in your first and last name and middle initial.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn on macro´s in LibreOffice. Tools / Options / LibreOffice / Advanced
2. Create a macro that inserts a special character eg #. Save as lastposition1
3. Create a macro that searches for this character and deletes it.  (use the delete function in the menu).  Save as lastposition2
4. Go to Tools / Customize / Events and select Save in LibreOffice. The name of the current document is the default saving position. Great! But this is a function you want to use for all documents.
5. Assign the macro´s to opening and closing the documents.

When you close LibreOffice it will ask is you want to save your document, even if you have not changed a thing for it will add the special character # before closing. This way you will always find yourself in the position in the document where you last changed something.